# what is the best way to display JSON data in ListViews in android

Tags: android, json, listview

I get a **json array** from my volley request

i get a list of Employees in json as a jsonObject what is the efficient way to display them in a ListView in android

```
 public class Employee{
        private  String Name;
        private  int Age,Pay;



    public  Movie(String Name,int Age ,int Pay){
        this.Name=Name;
        this.Age =Age ;
        this.Pay=Pay;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return Name;
    }

    public void setName(String Name) {
        this.Name= Name;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return Age;
    }

    public void setAge(int Age) {
        this.Age= Age;
    }

    public int getPay() {
        return Pay;
    }

    public void setPay(int Pay) {
        this.Pay= Pay;
    }
}
```

in my json request i parse it as

```
     private List<Employee > empList= new ArrayList<Employee >();
     for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                            try {
     JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);
                                Employee emp= new Movie();
                                emp.setName(obj.getString("Name"));
                                emp.setAge((obj.getInt("Age"));
                                emp.setPay(obj.getInt("Pay"));
                                empList.add(movie);
}
```

My main concern is that do i have to really create these many objects for each employee entry , if i have to display **1000 employee** details would it not be a concern to performance of the app

Comment: You should try [Retrofit](https://square.github.io/retrofit/) or [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) to avoid creating objects

Comment: Use Adapters for list. coz you can customise the view in that.

Comment: Yes, you have to create the same number of objects(As retrofit also do the same thing in the background as you are doing here but with little fast performance) but if you are a concern for performance you can go with the load more with 50 records at a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you need to iterate the every object just like you are doing but if you don't want that overhead you can use `retrofit` with `gson` that will give you the `object list` directly(but behind the scene that also iterate every object).

Answer (score 1):

First of all, try using Gson for parsing your json.
And if you want a better performance, try using RecyclerView instead of listview. Then you will have no problem to display *1000 employee* as you said.
Also using a constructor for your object is a better solution than setters.

Answer (score 0):

You should go with retrofit and Gson to avoid manual JSON parsing. And for performance enhancement you should use RecyclerView instead of ListView with lazy loading. If your data is too much large then you can divide in slot of 50 records and further request for load more data.